# Why the Python Scrapy library class isn't executed

Tags: python, scrapy, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Scrapy on IBM cloud as a function. My `__main__.py` is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AutoscoutListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vehicles list"

    def __init__(self, params, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AutoscoutListSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        make = params.get("make", None)
        model = params.get("model", None)
        mileage = params.get("mileage", None)

        init_url = "https://www.autoscout24.be/nl/resultaten?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page=1&cy=B&mmvmd0={0}&mmvmk0={1}&kmto={2}&atype=C&".format(
            model, make, mileage)
        self.start_urls = [init_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get total result on list load
        init_total_results = int(response.css('.cl-filters-summary-counter::text').extract_first().replace('.', ''))
        if init_total_results > 400:
            yield {"message": "There are MORE then 400 results"}
        else:
            yield {"message": "There are LESS then 400 results"}


def main(params):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    try:
        process.crawl(AutoscoutListSpider, params)
        process.start()
        return {"Success ": "The crawler (make: {0}, model: {1}, mileage: {2}) is successfully executed.".format(
            params['make'], params['model'], params['mileage'])}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"Error ": e, "params ": params}
```

The whole process to add this function is as follows:

1. `zip -r ascrawler.zip __main__.py common.py` // Thus I create a zip file to upload it. (*There is also a common.py file. I removed it from here for simplicity.*)
2. `ibmcloud wsk action create ascrawler --kind python:3 ascrawler.zip` // Create the function and add it to cloud
3. `ibmcloud wsk action invoke --blocking --result ascrawler --param make 9 --param model 1624 --param mileage 2500` // Invoke the function with parameters

After executing step three I get results as follows:

```
{"Success ": "The crawler (make: 9, model: 1624, mileage: 2500) is successfully executed."}
```

Thus I do not get any errors, but it didn't come in `AutoscoutListSpider` class at all. Why?

It should return also `{"message": "There are MORE then 400 results"}`. Any idea?

When I run it from python console as follows:

```
main({"make":"9", "model":"1624", "mileage":"2500"})
```

It returns correct result:

```
{"message": "There are MORE then 400 results"}
{"Success ": "The crawler (make: 9, model: 1624, mileage: 2500) is successfully executed."}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up, I'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @JamesThomas Ok. Thanks

Comment: Good news, everything is working! That information is written to the console logs, not returned from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"message": "There are MORE then 400 results"}` is available in the activation logs for the invocation, not the action result.

Once you have run the `ibmcloud wsk action invoke` command, retrieve the activation identifier for the previous invocation.

```
$ ibmcloud wsk activation list
activations
d13bd19b196d420dbbd19b196dc20d59 ascrawler
...
```

This activation identifer can then be used to retrieve all console logs from stdout and stderr written during the invocation.

```
$ ibmcloud wsk activation logs d13bd19b196d420dbbd19b196dc20d59 | grep LESS
2018-06-29T08:27:11.094873294Z stderr: {'message': 'There are LESS then 400 results'}
```

Comment: Any idea why that doesn't work `zip -r ascrawler.zip venv/bin/activate_this.py venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven-6.9.0.dist-info __main__.py common.py db.py` ? I want to use raven to capture errors, and I did like in your tutorial but I get an error `"error": "The action did not return a dictionary."`. And in logs `.....<module>",
  "2018-07-04T12:55:56.590718898Z stderr: from raven import Client",
  "2018-07-04T12:55:56.590724452Z stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'raven'"`